# JavaScript closure - Why is only result3()'s output affected by nAdd()?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function f1() {　　　　
    var n = 999;　　　　
    nAdd = function() {
        n += 1
    }　　　　
    function f2() {　　　　　　
        alert(n);　　　　
    }　　　　
    return f2;　　
}　　
var result1 = f1();
var result2 = f1();
var result3 = f1();　　

nAdd();
result1();  //999
result2(); //999
result3(); //1000
```

Messing around with this code example, I came to the conclusion that calling `nAdd()` only affects the closure nearest to it.

Example: `result3()`'s output is 1000.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with when `nAdd` is assigned the function. Note that when you create a closure, a new "copy" (for lack of a better word) of the local variables are created. Thus, `result1`'s `n` is different from `result2`s `n` which is different from `result3`'s `n`. They are seperate, and each closure cannot access another closure's `n`.

Look at this line:

```
nAdd = function() {
     n += 1;
}
```

This assigns `nAdd` a new closure each time. Each time, this closure will only affect the most recent "copy" of `n`.

So when you are doing.

```
var result1 = f1(); // assign nAdd for the first time, referring to result1's n.
var result2 = f1(); // re-assign nAdd, now it affects result2's n.
var result3 = f1(); // re-assign nAdd, now it affect result3's n.
```

`nAdd` got assigned a new closure each time. The last time, `nAdd` got assigned a closure with `result3`'s copy of n.

Thus, when you do `nAdd()`, you only increment `result3`'s `n`.

Here's an example that might clear things up.

```
function f1() {　　　　
    var n = 999;　　　　
    nAdd = function() {
        n += 1
    }　　　　
    function f2() {　　　　　　
        alert(n);　　　　
    }　　　　
    return f2;　　
}　　
var result1 = f1();
var nAdd1 = nAdd;
var result2 = f1();
var nAdd2 = nAdd;
var result3 = f1();　　
var nAdd3 = nAdd;

nAdd3();
result1();  //999
result2(); //999
result3(); //1000
nAdd1();
result1(); // 1000
nAdd1();
result1(); // 1001
nAdd2();
result2(); // 1000
nAdd();
result3(); // 1001 (the most recent nAdd result3's n).
```

To further elaborate, consider what would happen if you did this instead:

```
var result1 = f1();
nAdd();
var result2 = f1();
var result3 = f1();　

result1(); // 1000
result2(); // 999
result3(); //999
```

Or this:

```
var result1 = f1();
var result2 = f1();
nAdd();
var result3 = f1();　

result1(); // 999
result2(); // 1000
result3(); // 999
```

It becomes obvious that `nAdd` updates only the most recent invocation's `n`.!

Comment: "This assigns nAdd a new function each time. Each time, this function will only affect the most recent copy of n." Why the function only affect the most recent copy of n????

Comment: @Tommy A new set of local variables is created each time. When you assign the closure to nAdd, the closure refers to the most recent set of local variables. However, you overwrite nAdd every time you call the function. Thus. nAdd only refers to the most recent invocation's variables (which you assign to result3), so it only affects result3's n. Try moving the nAdd invocation to before you assign to result3 and see how it affects your output!

Comment: @GiorgianThanks! Your answer & Elune's answer are both nice! I think I deal it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be clear about the following thing:

nAdd is a global scoped function. But it is using a local scoped variable n.

Every time you re-create f1(), the pointer of nAdd function will change.

Finally it will changed to the closest f1() closure and the n variable inside nAdd function will also point to the closest f1() closure. So it can only change the value of the closest one.

Comment: Thanks! 'the pointer of nAdd function will change.' is so important.I deal it!